# Pyqt5-tools installation error on Widows 11

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

Downloading when I downloaded Pyqt5. But when I try to download Pyqt5-Tools, I'm getting an error.

I using Windows 11

When using Windows 10, it was easily downloaded. But Windows 11 has not been installed after installing.

```
pip install pyqt5-toolsCollecting pyqt5-toolsUsing cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\imran\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from pyqt5-tools) (8.1.2)Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)Collecting pyqt5==5.15.3Using cached PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz (3.3 MB)Installing build dependencies ... doneGetting requirements to build wheel ... donePreparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... errorerror: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.│ exit code: 1╰─> [29 lines of output]Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheelhook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheelAttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mym69u8_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
    File "C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mym69u8_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mym69u8_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ebfgqguq\pyqt5_e2d6632ee7174ad58d61d88e0ddffdcd\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mym69u8_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mym69u8_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mym69u8_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Do you have the latest pip version? Can you try to update?

Comment: See the bug-tracker: [Issue-98 - Python 3.10 support?](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98). There's a suggested [work-around given here](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98#issuecomment-968296553) which appears to solve the problem (but I can't test it myself). Alternatively, you could also just downgrade to Python-3.9, which is currently the highest supported version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here.
I had the Python 3.10 installed, but I found out that PyQt5 is not supported on the 3.10 version of Python. You can check this info [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/).

So I downgraded my Python version and everything worked fine.